# inflated view does not appear

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a simple TextView with the following xml markup under the file view_inflated.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:text="Inflated view"
    >
</TextView>
```

I want to inflate the TextView inside a LinearLayout declared under the file activity_main.xml as follows:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
          >

        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Now for inflating the view I tried like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        resource=new String[]{"Arafat","Anik","Prottoy","Progga","Prapti",
                "Oishy","Nijha","Adil","Troyee","Kushum","Manik","Shahin","Limon"
                ,"Shumon","Lipi","Lucy","Shaikot"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,resource);

        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_inflated, null);
        LinearLayout rl=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll1);
        rl.addView(v);
    }
```

Problem is-the list view appears as expected but the TextView doesn't appear. How to fix this issue ?

Comment: try setting a fixed height to listview

Comment: @Raghunandan The list might be larger in future. So I am not going to set a fixed height. Any other way ?

Comment: Meaning is to set temporary and check.

Comment: add the view as a footer to listview. so when you scroll you will see the textview.

Comment: @Raghunandan no difference after adding as a footer

Comment: @Md.ArafatAlMahmud you will see the textview if you do it right. show us what you have done.

Comment: you are inflating the android.R.layout instead of your layout :).

Comment: @DharaShah nope actually :) problem was solved with setting android:orientation="vertical" as Brontok suggested in his answer :)

Comment: ohh .. :).. nice nice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messing around with your problem for a while now and then figured out what you have missed

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

in your **activity_main.xml :)**

Do it and your problem will get solved.

To set textview at top, Replace your main layout with Relative Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

TypeCast in the code as well and then add  view to this Relative Layout prior setting adapter to list.

Like this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_inflated, null);
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll1);
    rl.addView(v);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resource);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: one more interrupt please :) The TextView gets added below the ListView but I want the reverse. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Add your inflated view as a footer to listview.

Before `setAdapter`

```
 lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
 LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
 View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_inflated, null);
 lv.addFooterView(v);
 lv.setAdapter(adapter);
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: yes it appears as a footer now. But I don't always want it to be a footer. Rather I want to use it as flexibly as possible.

Comment: well set the height of listview to a fixed height. your listview will still be scrollable so no problem By the way what do you mean by flexible as possible. elaborate. you could also use a relative layout have a textview at the bottom and listview at the top of it. no  need to inlfate a layout

Comment: I want the list view to appear below the textview. This is one example of flexibility. I want another view to be added between the listview and the textview, this is another.

Comment: @Md.ArafatAlMahmud 1. add it as a header to listview. 2. have a relative layout add textview at the top and add listview below textview. " I want another view to be added between the listview and the textview, this is another" have a textview at the top and liner layout with a fixed height below it and listview below linear layout inflate a view add the view to linear layout.

Comment: @Md.ArafatAlMahmud or have a linearlayout / relativelayout at the top with a fixed height and listview below it. Inflate a layout with textview or other view. add the inflated view to the linearlayout/relative layout. But still i am confused as to what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Brontok has solved the problem I was actually facing :) Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions. I have learnt a lot of new things from them :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.view_inflated,resource);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Section ListView**

[image]

You can refer to this below link

http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-section-listview.html

Hope this help.